# Rails / amazon aws s3 syntax error '@@{' not allowed as a class variable name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, syntax-error

I'm trying to install twitter bootstrap into my rails via the following command:

```
rails g bootstrap:install
```

It's triggering this error:

```
/home/!!!!/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:223:in `class_eval': /home/!!!!/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:223: `@@{' is not allowed as a class variable name
/home/!!!!/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:223: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
    unless defined? @@{:instance_writer=>true}
                      ^ (SyntaxError)
from /home/!!!!/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:223:in `block in cattr_reader'
```

how can I fix this? I'm not sure if this is an error in my code or some sort of conflict in the libraries. Thanks!

Comment: aws-s3 seems to be a gem that's been unchanged for the past 2 years. a lot has changed since the, in both ruby and rails. If I'm correct regarding the age of the gem, I'd highly recommend using a different one, perhaps the official SDK from Amazon, which works quite well and it's easy to use.

Comment: Ah okay I'll give the SDK gem a go, thanks!